Why i got this error trying to import Parametric UMAP
I am trying to use Parametric UMAP, using this code:
from umap import ParametricUMAP
p_embedder = ParametricUMAP()

And this error happens:
C:\Users\ldsp_\miniconda3\envs\tf-gpu\lib\site-packages\umap\__init__.py:16: UserWarning: The umap.parametric_umap package requires Tensorflow > 2.0 to be installed.
            You can install Tensorflow at https://www.tensorflow.org/install

            or you can install the CPU version of Tensorflow using 

            pip install umap-learn[parametric_umap]

            
  warn(
Traceback (most recent call last):

  Cell In[7], line 1
    p_embedder = ParametricUMAP()

  File ~\miniconda3\envs\tf-gpu\lib\site-packages\umap\__init__.py:26 in __init__
    raise ImportError(

ImportError: umap.parametric_umap requires Tensorflow >= 2.0

But I have tensorflow 2.8.0 installed, check pip list:
Package                       Version
----------------------------- -------------------
tensorboard                   2.8.0
tensorboard-data-server       0.6.1
tensorboard-plugin-wit        1.8.1
tensorflow                    2.8.0
tensorflow-estimator          2.5.0
tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem  0.31.0
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.

I searched around, but did not found anything related to this issue at UMAP Github repository. Any ideas what could be causing this error and how to fix it?

It was not because of tensorflow. It is because of Keras, as you can see here
It needs Keras > 3.0. My Keras was also at 2.8.
